# sparkpost undefined function status

Tags: wordpress, system-status

Can't load system status after upgrading from 4.7.31 to 5.2.2 on latest WP. When I try, Console shows `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/status` and the page is blank. Error log shows

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   civicrmVersion() in
>   /wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/com.cividesk.email.sparkpost/sparkpost.php
>   on line 145

Tried disabling Asset Caching (in Debugging & Error Handling) to no avail. Also installed latest Sparkpost for WP, but no change. What might cause this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

My bad -- I had botched the installation of the [Sparkpost release for Civi 5.x compatibility](https://github.com/cividesk/com.cividesk.email.sparkpost/issues/60). Once I realized the error of my ways, I put the Sparkpost files into the correct directory, and now Status page is happy again. No more errors!